# upload an image using busboy meanstack undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, busboy

I'm trying to make a sign up form with an image upload ability so I take the values on the ejs side using this by a post and enctype = "multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" action= "/SignUp" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" value="<%= locals.firstName || '' %>" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" value="<%= locals.lastName || '' %>" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="<%= locals.username || '' %>" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class = "from-group">
      <label for = "Image">Image</label>
      <input Content-Type = "multipart/form-data" type ="file" name = "Image" id = "Image" class = "form-control" required/>
    </div
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        <a href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

and I handle it from the server side using busboy

```
  SignUp:function(req,res){
  let reg = new Registrations();
  var busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 6*1024*1024 //2MB limit
    }
  });
    var stream;
    var fstream;
       busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
         if(fieldname == 'firstName')
         reg.firstName = val;
         else if (fieldname == 'lastName')
          reg.lastName = val;
          else if(fieldname == 'username')
          reg.username = val;
          else {
            reg.password = val;
          }


       })
      busboy.on('file', function(fieldname,file, filename,encoding,mimeType){
      stream = __dirname + '/img/' + filename;
      fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/img/' + filename);
      file.pipe(fstream);
      fstream.on('close', function(){
          reg.Image = stream;
        reg.save(function(err,reg){
          if(err){
            res.send(err.message)
            console.log(err);
          }else{
            console.log(reg);
          }
        })
      })
    })
    busboy.on('finish', function() {

    })
    res.render('login');

  }
```

it shows me this error every time I try it
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined on the line

```
req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname,file, filename,encoding,mimeType)
```

Can you please tell me what is this problem about ?

Comment: Now it does not show the error anymore but the fields are not received and I can't save them on mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used multer instead and it worked correctly

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Answer (score 0):

After a first look into the [busboy-doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy), it seems to me, as busboy is no middleware, which is extending the request, see the code snippet:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file',...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used **busboy** to upload images and I will share with you the configs and how its done.

1. Import the busboy module

   var Busboy = require('busboy');
2. Then inside your **post** endpoint declare busboy object

   ```
   var busboy = new Busboy({
     headers: req.headers,
     limits: {
       fileSize: 6*1024*1024 //2MB limit
     }
   });
   ```
3. Followed by the rest of the code inside the **post endpoint**

   ```
   busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
          //extract intput-field from upload-form
   });


   busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
         //process each file upload, check for size, mimetype, 
         //store if all checks passed, delete otherwise, move to 
         //next file
   });


   //finish call back when all files are uploaded
   busboy.on('finish', function() {
       //do cleanup and other related work 
   });

   return req.pipe(busboy);
   ```

I have created a gist off the project where I used **busboy** for uploading multiple images with following checks

1. Extract the input fields from the upload form
2. Make sure that file size is not over specified XMB
3. Make sure that the mimetypes are valid
4. As soon as a file is found with over XMB (X.1MB) then abort the upload and move to the next file
5. If file satisfies all checks then store it locally

Here is the link to the public gist [Upload Multiple Files with Busboy Nodejs ExpressJS](https://gist.github.com/rhamedy/8f29ec90a00fcf8fec8f2c82bd34d10e)

Comment: what is the on('field',...) for ?

Comment: that's the callback that will extract the input fields of the upload form, basically any field that is not of type file (i.e. firstName, lastName, etc.)

Comment: I adapted my module based on yours. The error is gone, but it's not even receiving the fields now ( firstName, etc....). Do you think I'm handling it correctly from the html side ? I edited my question's code if you want to have a look

Comment: can you put some console logs to see whether the **on field** is invoked or not? if yes invoked then what is the value of the **fieldname** for which its invoked. As long as in your form the input fields are before the file field, it should be accessible.